# pgadmin join fields from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, select, pgadmin

I am trying to combine data from two tables in pgadmin.

I can access both tables fine on their own.

Table 1:

```sql
SELECT candidateid ,date, "time", campaign_id,emailaddress, email_size, subject_length, email_length FROM dbo.learningtokenopenemail
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT city, emailaddress, country FROM dbo.candidatedetails
```

What would be the easiest way to add city and country to table one?

Answer (score 1):

You can join on the `emailaddress`:

```sql
SELECT l.candidateid,
       l.date,
       l."time",
       l.campaign_id,
       l.emailaddress, 
       l.email_size,
       l.subject_length,
       l.email_length,
       c.city,
       c.country
FROM   dbo.learningtokenopenemail l
JOIN   dbo.candidatedetails c ON l.emailaddress = c.emailaddress
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I entered what you suggested and it did not work

Comment: @FinlayMacFarlane care to elaborate on "it did not work"?

Comment: Apologies was late last night the error I got was ERROR:  column reference "candidateid" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT candidateid,
               ^
SQL state: 42702
Character: 8

Comment: @FinlayMacFarlane apparently you have columns with the same names in both tables. Fully qualifying them will solve the issue - see my edited answer

Comment: You are a legend and I appreciate the help so much :) thanks again

Comment: Good answer. Finlay, you should acknowledge Mureneik's answer as solution (tick the check mark below it to make it turn green) and also vote it up. You may want to look into INNER JOINS. They require a reference from one table to another, which in your case would be the email address. Make sure you understand the concept of INNER JOINS. That will help you a long way in managing databases.